# Cannot display the image in web browser provided by Python via Apache Server

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I am trying to display an image file in web browser via the Apache server by Python. I am using:
windows 7
apache http server 2.2
python 2.7

Configuration in httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs"
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$       /imagetest.py?img=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`imagetest.py` under htdocs folder :

```
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
imgName = form.getvalue("img")
print "Content-type: image/jpeg"
print
print file(r"C:/imageFolder/" + imgName, "rb").read()

# Also tried 
# sys.stdout.write( "Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n" + file("C:/imageFolder/" + imgName, "rb").read() )
# instead of "print"s above
```

The `http://localhost/images/0001.jpg` URL gives;
- `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors` error at Firefox,
- nothing at Chrome.
But in both cases the image fetched (about 1 MB) with http status code 200 (looked with Firebug).
Any suggestions?
Additionally, is it right way of doing stuff like this way? I decided to use cgi because of this server will serve nothing but images and some video files indirectly (namely via python script). I mean, no complicated operations there. However this server should handle many requests fast and reliable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.read()` is *not* guaranteed to read the entire file. Use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy the file contents to `sys.stdout`.

Or, better yet, enable and use [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

Comment: Thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I got rid of all file IO code lines by using mod_xsendfile.